# What's the difference between the two suffixes -то and -нибудь?

Tags: выбор-слова

Can someone, somehow please explain what the differences are between the suffixes -то and -нибудь? They tend to decorate words like как, кто, где, что, когда́ as in

как-то, как-нибудь (somehow)
кто-то, кто́-нибудь (someone, somebody)
где-то, где-нибудь (somewhere, someplace)
куда́-то, куда́-нибудь (somewhere)
что-то, что-нибудь (something)
когда́-то (sometime in the past?)
когда́-нибудь (some time in the future?)

Answer (score 5):

I'm not a linguist or a teacher, but this is how I understand it:

как-то is somehow, как-нибудь is also somehow, but it also can mean anyhow, in any way.

So, in the similar manner:

кто-то = someone, кто́-нибудь = anyone or whoever

где-то = somewhere, где-нибудь = somewhere, but not important where, someplace or wherever

куда́-то = somewhere, куда́-нибудь = anywhere

что-то = something, что-нибудь = anything

когда́-то = sometime, когда́-нибудь = some not specific (anytime) time

Answer (score 5):

That's a really complicated question if you want every single of these discussed with examples

Long story short, **-нибудь** refers to a hypothetical object: you have an idea that something might fit your description, but maybe such object does not exist at all. If it exists, it does not quite matter, which one. *Кто-нибудь* and *что-нибудь* may also refer to a choice from a set of *known* objects when it *does not matter* which one is chosen.

**-то** refers to a real but **unidentified** object. It is a certain object, but you do not know what it is.

This makes them not interchangeable in some contexts.

#### Past

In questions, assumptions and suggestions about the past it is OK to use *кто-нибудь* and *что-нибудь*. In statements, you cannot use them in the past. After all, if you are sure the event happened, then its participants are real—even if you do not know them:

- *Question*: Кто-нибудь из вас раньше здесь был?
- *Assumption*: Если бы кто-нибудь тут был, он бы тебя увидел. = If anyone were here, they would see you.
- *Assumption*: Тебя мог кто-нибудь увидеть.= Someone might have seen you (кто-то is also possible)
- *Statement*: Тут кто-то был. = Someone was here.
- *Statement*: Начальник что-то тебе принёс. = The boss brought something for you.

#### Future

In the future "кто-нибудь" is used more freely that "кто-то", because most "something/someone" sentences about future are suggestions, anyway:

- Кто-нибудь всё узнает и расскажет остальным. = Someone will find out everything and will tell the others.

#### "Some time"

"Когда" is time-related by itself, so its suffixed versions are quite different in usage.

- **когда-то** is typically used in the past to refer to some distant times in the past, "once".
- **когда-нибудь** is either used for the past ("*ever*") or for indefinite future ("*some day*"). If you are absolutely sure an event is bounf to happen, you can use "когда-то", too:

  - Он точно *когда-то/когда-нибудь* попадётся. = He is sure to get caught some day.

There exist a few additional meanings for a few of them:

- **как-нибудь** may be used colloquially to refer to "someday, when you have time" etc.—for example, when inviting someone to hang out with you.
- **где-то** is often used colloquially as "about, approximately", even though such usage is not acceptable for formal writing.

Comment: +1 but not sure about _когда-нибудь_ for the past.

Comment: @jwalker I am not sure about the specifics either. I'd like to have more examples but cannot think of those different from the ones I have. I definitely need more assumption-like sentences, since these seem to be the most shaky topic (I asked a few friends, and our opinions sometimes differed).

Comment: It is quite possible to use когда-нибудь for the past in the sense of "ever". Ex.: Tы когда-нибудь там был? Have you ever been there?

Comment: @Серж That's exactly what I wrote.

Comment: Yes, I know! But  jwalker said that he wasn´t sure about **когда-нибудь for the past**.

Comment: That why I left a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Russian "-нибудь" is like English "-ever".

кто-нибудь - whoever, где-нибудь - wherever, когда-нибудь - whenever etc.

The word "кто-нибудь" is derived from "кто ни будь" i.e. "кто (бы) ни был" - which means "whoever (was)". The others have similar origin and meaning.

Answer (score 1):

The way I used to describe the difference to an English speak is to draw a parallel with prefixes *some-* and *any-*, specifically:

> кто-то / кто́-нибудь
>   somebody / anybody
>
> где-то / где-нибудь
>   somewhere / anywhere
>
> что-то / что-нибудь
>   something / anything

It's slightly different with *как-то / как-нибудь*, and *когда-нибдь / когда-то* but the meaning stays the same:

> Он как-то это сделал
>   He did it somehow
>
> Как-нибудь сделаем
>   We'll do it somehow

You correctly identified that *-то* would normally be used with passed actions and *-нибудь* with the future ones.  In English this would also alter the meaning of the same *-how* word.